# Como puedo ver mi proyecto en localhost:3000 como antes de hacer el despliege en github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Despues de hacer un despliege de mi proyecto de react en github-pages me queda de esta manera: https://ast0m.github.io/Portfolio_react/ pero necesito hacer mas cambios y al hacerlos y ejecutar `npm start` me da esta respuesta

> Local:http://localhost:3000//ast0m.github.io/Portfolio_react   On Your
> Network:  http://192.168.1.64:3000//ast0m.github.io/Portfolio_react
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a
> production build, use npm run build.
>
> webpack compiled successfully

y al ingresar en la url que me proporciona, la pantalla esta en blanco y la consola
me da este error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

[image: Json de proyecto]

Comment: Podrá tener aglo que ver ese doble slash que tienes en la ruta?

Comment: Que tal FranAcuna, las he retirado pero continua igual. Creo que es un tema del build o del deploy porque me cambia a esa ruta que deberia ser localhost:3000

Comment: Puedes compartir tu `package.json` ?

Comment: Listo!! instale, github-pages para poder desplegar el proyecto y agregue homepage, predeploy y deploy.

Comment: Eso mismo queía ver, si tenías el script de deploy de github pages. Todavía sigue sin funcionarte?

Comment: Si, cuando ejecuto npm start me aparece el mensaje `Local:http://localhost:3000//ast0m.github.io/Portfolio_react On Your Network: http://192.168.1.64:3000//ast0m.github.io/Portfolio_react

Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully` pero cuando abro el enlace esta en blanco, solo me aparece el titulo del proyecto, me imagino que solo esta tomando el index.html

Comment: Deberías de usar `npm run predeploy`

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme. He intentado con ese comando pero sigo sin poder verlo en el localhost, exactamente que hace el predeploy?

Comment: El predeploy hace el build, el cual luego corres con npm start. En tu propiedad de homepage tienes un https://https para tu direccion, podrías corregir eso?

Comment: StackOverflow me edito el mensaje y lo hizo un link, en resumen, corrigue tu propiedad de `homepage` en tu `package.json`. Esa dirección es invalida

Comment: Que deberia de ir en homepage porque al cambiarla me da error.

Comment: Este fue el procedimiento que hice cuando agregue ese enlace [link](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1548-react/4065-guia-para-usar-github-pages-en-tus-proyectos-de-reactjs/)

Comment: Una ruta válida `https //https` NO es una ruta válida

Comment: No estás siguiendo el [paso 4](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#4-add-a-homepage-property-to-the-packagejson-file) de las instrucciones.

Comment: En el tutorial, la ruta que pone el creador es válida, la tuya no.

Comment: Listo FranAcuna, ese era el error. Muchas gracias!!